# Python if statement wont execute for csv

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to count the number of times a certain word appears in a csv file.

```
import csv

path = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\test.csv'
str = "line"
count = 0


with open(path,'rt',encoding="utf-8") as f :
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader :
       print(row)
       if str == row[0] :
       count = count + 1

print("\n \n The count is :",count)
```

Whenever i run the code, I always get the output 0 for count. However, all the rows are printed out. My csv file is has two columns, id and text and the data is as below :

```
id               text
1                this is line 1
2                this is line 2
3                this is line 3
4                this is line 4
```

You can see that all the lines contain str and the count should be 4 but it is always printed as 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There appaers to be an intendation error: `count = count + 1`

Comment: I think it should be 'if str == row[1]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

count = 0
find = 'line'

with open('test.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        line = ', '.join(row)
        if find in line:
            count = count + 1

print('The count is :', count)
```

FYI: You can avoid join if you want to calculate how many times word appears in the file. Just read file by lines without the csv module.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But what do you mean by reading without csv module? Treat the file as a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Specify 'newline' , 'delimiter' and 'quote char' exactly to get your desired result when opening csv file. See the example below:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` to look for your string.

**Ex:**

```
with open(path,'rt',encoding="utf-8") as f :
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader :
       print(row)
       if str in row[1] :
           count = count + 1
```

*Edit as per comment*

```
import csv
checkStr = 'line'
result = []
with open(path,'rt',encoding="utf-8") as f :
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader :
       if checkStr not in row[1]:    #Check if 'line' not in row
           result.append(row)

with open(filename,'w') as f:        #Write new result. 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

- Append all rows that do not have `checkStr`
- Write the result to new file.

Comment: Tried that but the error still persists. Still getting count to be 0

Comment: Updated snippet use `row[1]`

Comment: Please accept one of the ans that helped you. Thanks

Comment: Any idea how i could delete the entire row if it contains str? That would be helpful and would certainly save me from starting another thread

Comment: Updated snippet. Please check.